# React router and asp.net server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using reactjs.net library to render on asp.net server my react app (currently one list of some items with some filters on left side and pagination on bottom). It works fine but I can't figure out how to combine it with react router. This is my route configuration:

```
<Router>
   <Route path="/"      component={MainComponent}>
   </Route>
    </Router>
```

When route is matched on client side I get empty list( because I have setState to empty array if no props are supplied).  On server it is rendered with mvc razor helper and props are supplied so my list is not empty). When some filter(checkbox) is clicked ajax gets new objects. All expected behaviour but I don't want that first route matching erases my list. It seems shouldComponentUpdate method does not help here because it is not triggered on first render.